# Can't display mysql result data under its relevant <thead> days field?

Tags: php, arrays, html, multidimensional-array, logic

I created attendance chart in php from return database result.But it doesn't display under its relevant day rows (thead).I got db result in multi array like below `print_r($data)`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [day] => 11,10,8,2,19,16,9,22,18,17,15,1
        [0] => 11,10,8,2,19,16,9,22,18,17,15,1
        [member_id] => test004
        [1] => test004
        [status] => 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
        [2] => 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
        [member_login_name] => test004
        [3] => test004
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [day] => 15,1,11,10,8,2,19,16,9,22,18,17
        [0] => 15,1,11,10,8,2,19,16,9,22,18,17
        [member_id] => c422a154-c0f9-11e4-a6dd-7a12eb6538e9
        [1] => c422a154-c0f9-11e4-a6dd-7a12eb6538e9
        [status] => 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
        [2] => 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
        [member_login_name] => suzin
        [3] => suzin
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [day] => 16,10,8,5,22,2,19,1,18,17,15,11,9,25
        [0] => 16,10,8,5,22,2,19,1,18,17,15,11,9,25
        [member_id] => admin
        [1] => admin
        [status] => 3,2,2,3,2,0,3,0,2,3,2,2,0,3
        [2] => 3,2,2,3,2,0,3,0,2,3,2,2,0,3
        [member_login_name] => admin
        [3] => admin
    )
    ....
```

`day` and `status` order is the same (eg.explode by `,` that two strings can use the same keys)

**HTML**

```
 <style>
   .listtbl{
        background: orange;
        border : 1px solid #333dd3;
      }
  .attend {
       background: green;
     }
  .leave{
       background: yellow;
     }
 .absent{
       background: red;
    }
 .half{
    background: pink;
    }
 </style>
  <table class="listtbl">
            <thead>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i <= date('t'); $i++) {
                echo "<th>Day " . $i . "</th>";
            }
            ?>                    
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($data as $result) {
                    $day = explode(",", $result['day']);
                    $status = explode(",", $result['status']);
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $result['member_login_name'] . "</td>";
                    for ($d = 1; $d <= date('t'); $d++) {
                        $j = array();
                        //only execute under today date
                        if ($d <= date('d')) {
                            foreach ($day as $key => $value) {
                                if($d == $value){
                                    $status[$key] == 0 ? $class = "attend" :($status[$key] == 1 ? $class = "leave" : ($status[$key]== 2 ? $class = "absent":$class= "half"));
                                    echo "<td class='$class'></td>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //day above today date
                        else {
                                echo "<td class='nothing'></td>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

It code is work fine ,i thought.But it doesn't display according to the order of `<th>` days.I want one is if `day` 18 with `status` 0 is must be under `<th>`18 field

This is my tried output..

[image]

Comment: `$day` is an array, why are you using it like a dictionary with key/value? Just use a normal for loop. Or create a dictionary with day/status pairs and use that.

Comment: please give the `output` table and print your array by `print_r`, so it is clear to us. use `<pre>` to print array.

Comment: @David,  please use `print_r` instead of `var_dump($data)`. before and after `print_r` use the `<pre>` and `</pre>`.

Comment: okey, wait will make an answer of it.

Comment: Here you have to do a sorting of `day` cause it is related with `status`. If it is possible then your solution will be easy.

Comment: @David, Check my answer. I think its okey now.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated PHP:**

```
foreach ($data as $result) {
    $day = explode(",", $result['day']);

    //changes these two line 
    $day_flip = array_flip($day);
    sort($day);

    $status = explode(",", $result['status']);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $result['member_login_name'] . "</td>";
    for ($d = 1; $d <= date('t'); $d++) {
        if ($d <= date('d')){
            /************* changes start ****************/
            $day_key = array_search($d, $day);
            if($day_key > -1){
              $key = array_search($d, $day_flip);
              $key = $day_flip[$d];
              @$status[$key] == 0 ? $class = "attend" : ($status[$key] == 1 ? $class = "leave" : ($status[$key]== 2 ? $class = "absent": $class= "half"));
              echo "<td class='$class'></td>";
            }
            else
              echo "<td class='nothing'>--</td>";
            /************* changes end  ****************/
        }
        else{
            echo "<td class='nothing'>--</td>";                 //day above today date
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Let me know is it your desired output for first 3 row??
[image]

Comment: The username shows different cause i design the array in my local pc for testing.

Comment: It's doesn't work when greater 25 day.(display none)

Comment: see `if ($d <= date('d'))`, this means the current date